# Using kafka streams trying to write messages from input topic to output topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

Below is my code logic trying to write data from one topic to another.

```
//Computational logic
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, String> kStream = builder.stream(topicName_In);
kStream.foreach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key = " + k + " Value = " + v));
//kStream.peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key = " + k + " Value = " + v));
kStream.to(topicName_Out);
Topology topology = builder.build();
```

**Input Topic data format:**
Simple Message-1

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "HelloStreams-564343a1-1709-4bae-8fe5-514b37eee595-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:80)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:765)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:943)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:764)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by IntegerDeserializer is not 4
```

Comment: What is your actual question? What resources did you use to create the KafkaStream example reading from one topic and writing to another? This seems to be the most basic thing one can do with kafkaStreams and wondering why it can not be searched on the web. Maybe it clarifies if you state a question...

Comment: I am new to Kafka, trying to read data from one topic and trying to write in another topic

Comment: Maybe try to start with the demo application mentioned in the [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/quickstart)

Comment: And as advice, don't forget to ask a real question when you post something on Stackoverflow. When you just post the error stack trace some people might not understand what you are actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this line

```
KStream<String, String> kStream = builder.stream(topicName_In);
```

I assume that your input data is Strings.

The error message says

```
Size of data received by IntegerDeserializer is not 4
```

This indicates, that you did configure `IntegerSerde` (either for the key and/or the value) but you would need to configure `StringSerde` to make it work.